# How to interpret the expression "Mine de rien, ça devait bien ..."?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

> Tu te rappelles les ouvrages  de Gilles Bakereel  ? ***Mine de rien, ça devait bien*** faire des années que les deux tableaux peints par  Gilles Bakereel  n’avaient pas été réunis dans le Musée du Louvre.

While I roughly understand this expression, its precise meaning eludes me here -- especially given that "mine de rien" seems to be interpreted in a few slightly different ways, depending on context.

Comment: Although one perfectly understands *ouvrages* in that sentence, I think French would rather use the word *œuvres* to talk about (a) particular painting(s), even when not referring  about the whole of a painter's work. *Ouvrages* would be the appropriate word  when talking about books though. Food for thought here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Mine de rien » et « ça devait bien … » sont deux groupes indépendants. D'abord, vérifie que tu comprends bien la phrase « ça devait bien faire des années que les deux tableaux [...] n'avaient pas été réunis [...] ». « Ça faisait des années que les deux tableau n'avaient pas été réunis » signifie que la dernière fois que les deux tableaux avaient été réunis date d'il y a plusieurs années (ou éventuellement qu'ils n'avaient jamais été réunis). Passer de « ça faisait » à « ça devait faire … » indique que ce n'est pas une affirmation certaine : « ça faisait » est une affirmation absolue, tandis que « ça devait faire » signifie « je pense que ça faisait ». L'adverbe « bien » accentue « des années », il tend à faire paraître l'intervalle de temps plus long (des années, peut-être même des décennies ?).

« Mine de rien » signifie que quelque chose est caché. Ce n'est pas forcément caché volontairement, ça peut très bien être quelque chose à laquelle personne ne faisait attention. Souvent, la visibilité en question est abstraite, par exemple un évènement inattendu (que l'on n'avait pas vu venir). Ici, « mine de rien » indique que le locuteur n'avait pas remarqué auparavant que les tableaux n'avait pas été réunis depuis longtemps. Ils n'avaient pas été réunis l'année dernière, ni l'année d'avant, ni ... Ah, oui, mine de rien, ça faisait longtemps.

Comment: Regarding the first half of your answer, that was exactly what I wanted to double-check! Thanks. :) Looks like I was on the right track, except for one point, though. Is it impossible to construe "bien" as qualifying and emphasising the function of "devait"? That is, a change from the simple "must" to the emphatic "MUST!!!"?

Comment: @Alone-zee It's possible, but it wouldn't be very emphatic in the sense of increasing the probability. In fact, “ça doit bien …” can even decrease the probability (“ça doit être possible” → I think it's possible, “ça doit bien être possible” → closer to I hope it's possible). In this sentence, I perceive *bien* as qualifying *des années*.

Comment: Hi. If "bien" qualifies "des années" like "tant d'années", I wonder if the word order isn't more like "ça devait faire **bien des années**" (just like "bien des choses") instead of "ça devait bien faire des années"?

Comment: @Alone-zee No, it's “ça devait bien faire des années que …”. I'm afraid I have no explanation for this, but as a native one way is natural and the other sounds strange.

Comment: Note that *ça devait faire bien des années* is possible too, but it doesn't fit well in this context. Gramatically, in *ça devait bien faire des années*, *bien* can't be attached to *des années*, but I agree with Gilles that the *bien* doesn't connote hope as in *ça doit bien être possible*. It's maybe closer to *at least*.

Comment: @Alone-zee Actually, on second thought, “ça devait faire bien des années” is ok, but it has a different meaning that doesn't fit in the context: “bien des années” means “a lot of years”, but it's a little strange to combine it with “devait” which implies some uncertainty.

Comment: Hi. So "ça devait **bien** faire des années" denotes a somewhat lower possibility than "ça devait/must faire des années", correct?

Comment: @Alone-zee Yes, a little.

Comment: I'd say "bien" is adding doubts and surprise. E.g. "Ca doit bien faire 50 kilos" is somewhere between "ça doit faire environ 50 kilos" and "ça doit faire au moins 50 kilos !".

Answer (score 1):

*Mine* peut avoir trois sens différents en français, dans l'expression *mine de rien*  le mot désigne l'apparence extérieure (et particulièrement le visage).  On emploie cette expression pour exprimer que la réalité est différente de ce qui est visible, ou de ce à quoi on aurait pu s'attendre.

- > Mine de rien, il a réussi à tous ces examens.

  Ça a le sens de « On ne s'y attendait pas mais.. / Contre toute attente... / C'est surprenant mais...). C'est le sens que je donne à l'expression dans la phrase donnée en exemple dans la question.
- > Mine de rien, il faut 5 heures pour aller jusqu'au sommet à pied.

  Ça a le sens de « On ne dirait pas mais... »
- > Il a mis la bouteille dans son sac et mine de rien  il a quitté le magasin sans payer.*

  Ça a le sens de « comme si de rien n' était », « sans rien laisser paraître ».

Je pense que pour chacun de ces exemples on emploierait des expressions différentes en anglais. (for guidance only as lots of other translations can be given: 1- *Despite all expectations*; 2- *you wouldn't think so at first sight*, 3- *innocently / casually*)

*<sub>Désolée pour cet exemple amoral, je ne trouve rien de mieux pour l'instant.</sub>

Comment: Hi. For my example sentence, how about the following interpretation? "Le fait que tant d'années s'étaient déjà écoulées **avait de quoi surprendre**, d'autant plus qu'**on ne risquait pas de s'en rendre compte**."

Comment: In English: "**Without us realising it (!!!)**, it must have been years since the two paintings had last been ..."

Comment: @Alone-zee "Le fait que tant d'années s'étaient déjà écoulées avait de quoi surprendre," is perfectly to the point. But I don't see why adding  "d'autant plus qu'on ne risquait pas de s'en rendre compte." Not linked to *mine de rien*,  it refers to the time elapsed between the two exhibitions. Did you want to say that the previous exhibition had gone unnoticed?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is meant "Without us realising it (!!!), it ...."

Comment: Oh, I see. :) It was an unnecessary addition, then.

Comment: @Alone-zee I think so. By the way I think we'd rather say **au** Musée du Louvre.

Comment: Got it! It was some time ago that I heard these sentences on a video, so alas it looks like I wasn't able to reconstruct everything perfectly from my memory. Please continue on with constructive nitpicking. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sans qu'on puisse s'y attendre. On dit aussi "l'air de rien" comme dans "l'air de rien (= avec son apparence modeste), il a été reçu brillamment.